Annotation labels in QGIS not aligned
I have a large data set of a base map for the city of Dresden. This was created in ArcGIS and is available as an .mxd file. Unfortunately, .mxd data cannot be easily imported into QGIS, so I imported the data into QGIS using .lyr, exported the annotations as feature classes and then added them to QGIS using a GDB.
I am very happy that I was able to import the annotations into QGIS, but the alignment is a problem. Since it is a very large dataset, I would hate to manually adjust each individual annotation.
Is there a way to center the annotations parallel to the nearest street?
As an explanation: There is the layer "Street labels" and the layer "Streets".

